# Installing specific versions of python dependencies for a package inside that package

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip

I have an installable python package (mypackage) and it needs to use specific versions of a number of dependencies. At the minute I have some .sh scripts that just pip these into an internal package folder (eg C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mypackage\site-packages). When mypackage executes it adds this internal folder to the beginning of the python path so that it will override any other versions of the required dependencies elsewhere in the python path.

I know this will only work if the user doesn't import the dependencies prior to importing mypackage but I will document this.

I want to remove the .sh scripts and integrate the above into either dist_utils install or pip standard installation process. What is the best way to do this? I know about `install_requires` but it does not seem to allow specification of a location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the virtualenv tool which solved the above problem much more elegantly than the solution I'd put in place:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html